# How to solve differential equations in matrix form

Tags: differential-equations

I want to directly solve the following differential equations in matrix form , what can be done to meet the requirements?
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{m1} & 0 \\
 0 & \text{m2} \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{x1}''(t) \\
 \text{x2}''(t) \\
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{k11} & \text{k12} \\
 \text{k12} & \text{k22} \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{x1}(t) \\
 \text{x2}(t) \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

It's troublesome to manually convert to list format every time. I want a general method:

```
s = NDSolve[{x1''[t] + 2 x1[t] - 2 x2[t] == 0, 
    x2''[t] - 2 x1[t] + 2*x2[t] == 0, x1[0] == x2[0] == 0, 
    x1'[0] == 0, x2'[0] == 2}, {x1, x2}, {t, 30}];

Plot[Evaluate@
   x1[t] /. s, {t, 0, 25}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Comment: Just code it as written...and apply `DSolve` (or `NDSolve` along with ICs).

Comment: For example, `DSolve[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2}].{x''[t], y''[t]} + {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}.{x[t], y[t]} == {0, 0}, {x, y}, t]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You don't have to convert to use `DSolve`, but there are other times you may want to convert your matrix equations to list equations.  `Thread` will do that for you so you don't have to do it manually.